# rbt setup-repo: No CVS repository found or selected for ipaddresshere/reviews

Tags: http, repository, cvs, python-2.6, review-board

Upon running rbt setup-repo, I get the error:

```
No CVS repository found or selected for ipaddresshere/reviews. . reviewboardrc not created.
```

ipaddresshere is the ip address of my computer on which the reviewboard server and site are set up on. The cvs repository is a remote repository with the path specified using pserver on my actual reviewboard site.

At the moment I have manually created a .reviewboardrc file with the reviewboard url which is myipaddress/reviews as well as the repository name and the repository type which is cvs. I am using ReviewBoard 2.0.17 and RBTools 0.7.4.

Running this command with --debug on give:

```
>>> RBTools 0.7.4
>>> Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:37:14) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]
>>> Running on Linux-2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.i686-i686-with-centos-6.6-Final
>>> Home = /root
>>> Current directory = /mydirectory/directory
Enter the Review Board server URL: localhost/reviews
>>> Running: git version
>>> Checking for a Subversion repository...
>>> Running: svn --non-interactive info
>>> Command exited with rc 1: ['svn', '--non-interactive', u'info']
svn: '.' is not a working copy
---
>>> Checking for a Git repository...
>>> Running: git rev-parse --git-dir
>>> Command exited with rc 128: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--git-dir']
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
---
>>> Checking for a Mercurial repository...
>>> Running: hg root
>>> Command exited with rc 255: ['hg', 'root']
abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
---
>>> Checking for a CVS repository...
>>> repository info: Path: cvsmachineip:/cvsroot/cvs, Base path: None, Supports changesets: False
>>> Making HTTP GET request to http://localhost/reviews/api/
>>> Making HTTP GET request to http://localhost/reviews/api/repositories/
>>> Cached response for HTTP GET http://localhost/reviews/api/repositories/ expired and was modified
No CVS repository found or selected for localhost/reviews. .reviewboardrc not created.
```

This is my first time using reviewboard and was given the task to put the reviewboard server on this machine, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened was I created my own .reviewboardrc file instead of running rbt setup-repo. In this file was the following:

```
REVIEWBOARD_URL="http://localhost/reviews"
REPOSITORY="myrepo"
```

This worked great and solved my problem as rbt setup-repo is very picky about the specified path.